# Where to get osm history extracts in 2019?

Tags: openstreetmap, osm-full-history

I was trying to make an animation of my city growing, but stumbled upon lack of data. In 2018 geofabrik stopped providing history extracts (osh.pbf), and that was the last source of history files, as I was able to find, all other links on the internet were dead long before.

So, where does one get cropped osm data with history in 2019?

Is processing a full history dump to extract local area a viable option for a modern desktop PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

History files are still available from Geofabrik! You need to use their "OpenStreetMap internal server" download area, and log on with your OSM account. This was changed last year to accomodate for GDPR requirements.

Link: https://osm-internal.download.geofabrik.de/

Comment: Huh, thanks! But they specifically say there that "These files must only be used for OpenStreetMap internal purposes, e.g. quality assurance. You must ensure that derived databases and works based on these files are only accessible to OpenStreetMap contributors." -- I'd like to post resulting animation in a social media (it won't contain user data, of course), does this apply?

Comment: Ask from the OSM project, perhaps via legal-questions https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Contact or just the talk mailing list.